# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit.cli' after upgrading to 1.21.0

Tags: python

I tried to upgrade streamlit to lastest version 1.21.0 but after upgrading I have an error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit.cli'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbn7Q.png)

Please tell me how to show problem.

I reinstall or reinstall and upgrade but cannot execute "streamlit run xxx.py" anymore

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your error as text and not as an image.